# Iterate childs and check when ready in angular2 observable

Tags: angular, typescript

i try to iterate over my child objects and set a preloadingDone flag, when all is successfully loaded.

```
this.HeaderService.getAll().subscribe(header => {
  header.forEach((headerline, index) => {
    this.SubService1.get(headerline.key).take(1).subscribe( sub1 => {
      this.SubService2.get(headerline.key).take(1).subscribe( sub2 => {
        if(index == header.length - 1){ // <-- not working !!! :-(
          preLoadingDone = true;
        }
      })
    })
  })
});
```

my if in this example code does not work, because of async issues. how can i solve my problem?

edit:
this servicecalls are placed in my ngOnInit(). and the problem is that i load in the subservices urls to show images in the template. if the preloading is not done before, i got a error in the console, because the image points to null

Comment: Subscribe has `three callbacks(next,error,complete)`. you could write your code in complete call back and I believe it should work .

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need to know the complete of the last interation of subservice2 to check if everything was loaded ;-)

Comment: y not just use `?` in template for image url instead..

Answer (score 0):

```
let __self = this;
__self.HeaderService.getAll().subscribe(header => {
  header.forEach((headerline, index) => {
    __self.SubService1.get(headerline.key).take(1).subscribe( sub1 => {
      __self.SubService2.get(headerline.key).take(1).subscribe( sub2 => {
        if(index == (header.length - 1)){ // <-- not working !!! :-(
          __self.preLoadingDone = true;
        }
      })
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: (header.length - 1) for mathamatical calculation

Comment: __self for keeping `this` scope alive during nested subscribes

Comment: I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: arrow function takes care of `this` scope

Comment: this servicecalls are placed in my ngOnInit(). and the problem is that i load in the subservices urls to show images in the template. if the preloading is not done before.. i got a error in the console, because the image points to null